# direct struct initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

What's the easiest way to translate this into a valid C++ 11 statement?

```
typedef struct S_NODE {
  short int total;
  short int move[3];
  int next[3];
} NODE;

NODE* trie = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
trie[0]=(NODE){0,{0,0,0},{-1,-1,-1}}; // invalid C++
```

The only way I can think of is

```
NODE node = {0,{0,0,0},{-1,-1,-1}};
trie[0]=node;
```

but reusing node as a temporary variable isn't possible then:

```
node = {1,{3,3,7},{1,2,3}};  // doesn't compile
```

Comment: `typedef struct X { ... } Y` is a C construct which you should unlearn in C++. In C++ when you define `struct X` you can use `X` as a type quite fine, without needing the `struct` prefix. And some things will only work with the real name, not with the typedef.

Comment: BTW, your code has some obvious errors: You define `NODE`, but then use `Node`. You name your variable `try`, but that's a C++ keyword. You initialize the variable with a null pointer, but then try to assign to element 0, which dereferences the null pointer.

Comment: fixed! And yes, I know it's old C code but that's the point: I'm trying to port this to C++ 11

Comment: What about using a constructor to initialise node, wouldn't that be more C++ like? Also can an initializer_list help? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code

```
trie[0] = {0, {0, 0, 0}, {-1, -1, -1}};
```

Compiles with both g++ and clang++ with the `-pedantic` switch. Brace initialization is introduced in C++11 which is mostly compatible with C99.

Comment: It doesn't with MS Visual Studio though. But yeah, I might go with the class-way...

Comment: @user1709708 Try the MSVS2012 November CTP update. This should just work without library support for braced-init-lists.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with this:

```
struct NODE {
  short int total;
  std::array<short int, 3> move;
  std::array<int, 3> next;

  NODE()
  : total(0) {
    move.fill(0);
    next.fill(-1);
  }
};

NODE trie; // everything is initialized automatically
```

That takes care of the default initialization.  As for the assignment of a big block of magic constants  as in `node = {1,{3,3,7},{1,2,3}}`, I think it'd be better to just set the values by name.

Comment: `std::array` doesn't have a member function `assign`, I think you're mistaking it for `fill`.

Comment: @MFH: you're right, I confused it with the Boost implementation, so fixed my answer.  Thanks.